# How do I redirect visitors to login page?

Tags: python, django

I have the following url handler in my main Django project `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^$', 'core.views.generic.index')
```

Instead of landing on the index page as above, I want users to land on the login page.

I have another `urls.py` in an app called `core` that sends visitors to the login page:

```
url(r'^/login$', private.MeLogin.as_view())
```

How can I send all the people visiting `url(r'^$', ...)` in my main app to `private.MeLogin.as_view()` in my core app?

**EDIT:**

I have tried the following,

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/#/login')
```

but I get that this page has a redirect loop

Comment: what’s wrong with using `url(r'^$', core.private.MeLogin.as_view())`?

Comment: When I change to that statement I get a login page with the header Django REST framework instead of my normal login page. I don't know why. Is it possible to just redirect the url to /login? I think that would be the best solution if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way to solve that be using a decorator, in this case login_required.
[Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required)

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required


@login_required
def index(request):
    index view code in here
```

What this will do is redirect you to your login view.
As mention in the Documentation
login_required() does the following:

- If the user isn’t logged in, redirect to settings.LOGIN_URL, passing the current absolute path in the query string.
- If the user is logged in, execute the view normally. The view code is free to assume the user is logged in.

You can also customize your decorator check the documentation for more information.

Comment: That looks like a good approach. I have tried @login_required(redirect_field_name='', login_url='#/login')
def index(request):
    return render_to_response('html/index.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request)) and it sends visitors to the right address. But they get a mesage that "This webpage has a redirect loop". Do you have any idea how I could resolve that?

Comment: If you're using class-based views, decorate the `.as_view() ` of those. As for the redirect loop... Aren't you trying to decorate the login page itself?

Answer (score 0):

To login required, you must use a decorator indicating that:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def index(request):
    return render(request,'home.html')
```

In any view that the login is required, just use it.